# Download .txt files from web using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, download, file-exists

I have managed to find a way to download .txt files from a website that i have access to which is great, but i am using a list of filenames i have added to a datagridview.

My next progression is to download any .txt files from the root and subdirectories on the website but if it exists in my download location c:\logs it will skip it.

Any direction is gratefully received. VBVirg

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim _FilePath As String = "<file path and name here>"
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExist(_FilePath) = True Then
    'File exists.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vincent's answer:

```
Dim FilePath As String = "YourFile"
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(FilePath) = True Then
    'File exists, delete it
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(FilePath)
Else
    'The file doesn't exist.
End If
```